# Do Korean anti-North Korean films mock the regime?

Tags: north-korea

Do films, either by former North Koreans or native South Koreans, that are anti-North Korea take the approach of mocking the regime as ridiculous or weak, as opposed to taking a serious approach and describing the regime as carrying out horrible human rights abuses?

Comment: Even though I don't know anything about Korean media I am quite confident that it should be possible to find examples for both.

Comment: Like any topic worthy of film, I'm sure both are done.

Comment: @blip well if you take the US films about the USSR, all of them are ridiculous and cannot be seen seriously.

Comment: @Anixx "ridiculous" isn't the same as "using ridicule".

Comment: Between North and South, there is cold war PR. They are part of the cold war PR. In the reality, the North Korean regime is strong, stable, brutal and very well determined.